# Facebook Fans clicking through are being prompted to "like" when they already have

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, click-through

I'm wondering if this isn't just an issue with these individual's cookies or browser settings, but here's the issue:

I'm moderating a Facebook business page for a website that hosts contests (requiring a click-through to the site), and out of several thousand successful entries we're getting just a handful of users complaining that they clicked through to our contest entry page and the site prompted them to sign in to Facebook when they already were -or asked them to "like" the page, while displaying below an image that declares that they already have.

I'm not sure what to tell them, but I don't want to just ignore the problem. Is there anything I can do or suggest to them to make this right?

***Update***
I've been told that it might be the app permissions might be set incorrectly for these profiles and that they could maybe remove the app and try again. Does that sound right?

Comment: Instructing them to go into their Facebook app permissions and remove our app, and then click through to the site again, seems to have helped a few of them. 

I'll just assume that's the fix for this one.